# What wood protection should I use for a kids swing set in the desert sun?

Tags: wood, sealing, staining, play-structures

I recently acquired this kids play-set which is all plastic except for the wood bars on the climbing net - see below:

[image]

I've read the answer to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5731/what-is-the-difference-between-various-wood-sealers) but am still unsure about what I should use to protect the wood. The set is about 5 years old and the wood is very dry and has small cracks. There will be kids climbing on it (obviously) and it's going to sit out in the Arizona sun all day long. What would you recommend I use to treat or seal these wood pieces and how long after treatment is it safe for kids to use?

Comment: The wood will likely outlast the plastic. If you can find a tree, maybe put it under the tree. (BTW, if you keep care of those plastic sets, they do tend to hold their value)

Answer (score 3):

A small can of deck sealant should suffice.  Follow manufacturer instructions, applying with a 1" trim brush.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of sealer or other treatment, I would just keep an eye on the ropes and rungs (the wood) and replace them when they seem to be about to break.

If the rope is nylon, the sun will affect that moreso than the wood.  But rope is cheap, and all you need is a drill to be able to replace the rungs.